# Attempted import error: 'messaging' is not exported from 'firebase/app'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

```html
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/messaging";

let messaging = null
if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {

   const initializedFirebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
   // Project Settings => Add Firebase to your web app
   apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY,
   authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
   databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DBURL,
   projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
   storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
   messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MSG_SENDERID,
   appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID
   });
   messaging = initializedFirebaseApp.messaging();
}  
export { messaging };
```

I am starting to run my server am getting failed to compile errors below Like this:

Attempted import error: 'messaging' is not exported from 'firebase/app' (imported as 'firebase').

How can i fix this ???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRHtW.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code; type the code out if you can. Also, the problem seems to lie in your /header/index.js, so can you also include that file's content in the question ?

Comment: `import firebase from 'firebase/app'; const messaging = firebase.messaging()`